# need some printing number pyramid

Tags: c, loops

I need to program a number pattern pyramid like that:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j, rows = 5;

  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Where am I doing wrong? I need to flip somehow the first triangle pattern and mix it with the second. Please help.

Comment: You should [edit] and add the desired output AS TEXT and your actual output AS TEXT. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I suggest you to start by figuring out how to print a single row number `i` and write a function for it such as `void print_row(int row_num, int total_rows);` here `total_rows` will be used to calculate the padding.

Comment: you need both a count down and count up on the same row. You don't print a newline until after both of them.

Comment: Somewhere you probably need to print a bunch of spaces before each line (except the last).

Comment: Search SO for `[c] number pyramid` and you'll find many similar questions.

Comment: FIrst of all: indent your code properly. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You're almost there. I'm sure you can solve this yourself. A piece of paper and a pencil might be helpful.

Comment: please , can soneone can write the solution ? then i will compare where is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your pyramid is 6 levels high. The max number is 5. This is not a coincidence. There is a direct relationship.

If `n` is `5`, you need to do something 6 times, from `0` to `n`. There's a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

On each row you need to do print from `i` to `0`, and then from `1` to `i`. That's two loops.

```
for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
    ...
}

for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    ...
}
```

Of course, you also need to indent a number of spaces inversely related to `i`, which is another loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= /* Fill in here for inverse relationship */; j++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to flip somehow the first triangle pattern and mix it with the second.

**TL;DR** The trick is very simple: your row index `i` should start from `|n - j|` (or `abs(n - j)`) where `j` is the column index and `n` is the number.

Here is how you can do it:

```c
for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
    for (int i = abs(n - j); i < nrows; ++i) {
        matrix[i][j] = '0' + abs(n - j);
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

Imagine you have a matrix. In order to build a pyramid with a number `n`, you will need:

- `n + 1` rows (since you will have `0` included in the top). Let's call it `nrows`.
- `2n + 1` columns (`2n` because the numbers will appear twice in a row, `1` because you will have one `0` per row). Let's call it `ncols`.

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10        
    - - - - - - - - - - - 
0 |           0
1 |         1 0 1
2 |       2 1 0 1 2
3 |     3 2 1 0 1 2 3
4 |   4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
5 | 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

**First**, you want to fill the first half, i.e. from column `0` to `n`: `for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j)`.

```
  J  | End | Start | Pattern of Start
---------------------------------------
  0  |  N  |   N   |     N - 0
---------------------------------------
  1  |  N  | N - 1 |     N - 1
---------------------------------------
  2  |  N  | N - 2 |     N - 2
---------------------------------------
 ... | ... | ..... |     N - J
---------------------------------------
  N  |  N  |   0   |     N - N
```

The pattern is: `for (int i = n - j; i < nrows; ++i)`. You would fill that first half with `n - j`.

**Second**, you want to fill the second half, i.e. from column `n + 1` to `2n`: `for (int j = n + 1; j < ncols; ++j)`.

```
   J   | End | Start |  Pattern of Start
------------------------------------------
 N + 1 |  N  |   1   | N + 1 - N = J - N
------------------------------------------
 N + 2 |  N  |   2   | N + 2 - N = J - N
------------------------------------------
 N + 3 |  N  |   3   | N + 3 - N = J - N
------------------------------------------
 ..... | ... | ..... | N + X - N = J - N
------------------------------------------
  2N   |  N  |   N   |   2N  - N = J - N
```

The pattern is: `for (int i = j - n; i < nrows; ++i)`. You would fill that second half with `j - n`.

Now, you can do two separate `for` loops to fill the first and second halves.

```c
// Fill first half
for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j) {
    for (int i = n - j; i < nrows; ++i) {
        matrix[i][j] = '0' + n - j;
    }
}

// Fill second half
for (int j = n + 1; j < ncols; ++j) {
    for (int i = j - n; i < nrows; ++i) {
        matrix[i][j] = '0' + j - n;
    }
}
```

You can write one `for` loop by replacing `n - j` and `j - n` with `abs(n - j)`, since both of them are positive values (see TL;DR above, or the code below).

---

**Full functionning code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_matrix(const int nrows, const int ncols, const char matrix[nrows][ncols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)
            printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
        
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void init_matrix(const int nrows, const int ncols, char matrix[nrows][ncols], const char value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = value;
}

void print_pyramid(const int n)
{
    // Calculate the number of rows and columns
    const int nrows = n + 1;
    const int ncols = n * 2 + 1;
    
    char matrix[nrows][ncols];
    
    // Initialization
    init_matrix(nrows, ncols, matrix, '\0');
    
    // Fill the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
        for (int i = abs(n - j); i < nrows; ++i) {
            matrix[i][j] = '0' + abs(n - j);
        }
    }
    
    // Printing
    print_matrix(nrows, ncols, matrix);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_pyramid(5); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include all 3 for loops in one for loop which runs 6 times. First you have to print spaces. Then first half of the triangle and then the other half. After that you have to print `\n` .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i, j,k,l;

   for (i = 0; i <=5; i++)
   {

       for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
       {
           printf("  ");
       }
       for (k = i; k >=0; k--)
       {
           printf("%d ", k);
       }
       for (l = 1; l <=i; l++)
       {
           printf("%d ", l);
       }
       printf("\n");

   }

}
```